# Trigger the deployment of an api through frontend UI

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Let's say I have deployed a full stack application in my minikube cluster(with frontend and several backend APIs), and I want the authentication api pod to scale from 0 replica to n only when I clicked "login" in the frontend UI, is it possible to achieve this through service discovery? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by "pod to speed up only when..." but if you mean that you want to have your app deployed, but scaled down to **0 replicas**, and only scale up to **n replicas** when there is traffic to the service, then [Knative Serving](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/) is an option.